# Vue custom delimiters not working in Firefox

Tags: django, vue.js, templatetags

I have a django project and I want to start adding Vue.js elements into it, but there is a big overarching issue before I can really start in that custom delimiters (template tags) do not work in the firefox browser only Chrome, I can change them from curly braces to square brackets, but in firefox it just renders the code not the message. The following code is not part of my django project, it is just example code to demonstrate the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <title>Learning Vue.js</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <input type="text" v-model="name" />
      <p>Hello [[ message ]]</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
    delimiters: ["[[","]]"],
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Hello World'
      };
    }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

So this code renders the following in Chrome:

```
Hello World!
```

And in Firefox, it renders the code:

```
[[ message ]]
```

I'm assuming there is a fix for this, as I almost never see rendered code in websites and I'm assuming Vue is popular, how do other developers get around this issue?

Comment: If downvoting, please explain why as this seems like a valid question without a solution to me.

Comment: you should have javascript disabled in firefox. same code should produce same output in firefox or chrome; (except IE)

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that I may have javascript turned off. No, I don't it's my main web browser and few sites load on it with Javascript disabled. I get what you are saying, but the above code works in Chrome and not in Firefox, try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: for me it's not working on Chrome. I haven't tried Firefox, but I think I will have same problem on Firefox.